# Laravel 5.7 - Api route basic not working

Tags: laravel

[Controller\Api\Auth\RegisterController.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxg86.png)

[\api.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mYwq.png)

[url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecEof.png)

I was code follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StFvAYmg04o&t=287s.

But the api route not working.

I search so many time but I can't find the way to process it. And all the api route not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like you are running under apache. Try running under the Laravel artisan server (`php artisan serve`).

Comment: are you testing the post to get that message or are you simply trying to access it with a get?

Comment: As @Luiz said use Laravel artisan server it'll solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Apache2 on Ubuntu and find fix for this issue by following command

1. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
2. `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
3. Find `<Directory /var/www/>` and change from `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Then restart Apache service. This is working in my case